# how to upload image file and json with Loopj AsyncHttpClient?

Tags: android, json, android-async-http, loopj

i want upload to Spring server @RequestBody

json and multipart-file(imgaefile) at ones.

how do i do?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I tried follow homepage guide. but RequestParam is not Resposebody

Comment: Finally i am success upload. image -> BASE64 text.... but i think this way is NOT Right way.

Comment: The ultimate goal of the question is find the better way upload to server.

Comment: Does not matter Library. if you know better than AsyncHttpClient Library, please share your's knowhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same requirement I have used this code to Put the the image into server

```
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    try {
        params.put("photo", FragmentPhotoCrop.croppedFile, "image/jpeg");  // croppedFile is a FIle 
        params.setUseJsonStreamer(false);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }

    asyncHttpClient.put(getActivity(), url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() { ..

       //enter code here

    }
```

Hope it may help :)